# transpose some SQL columns into rows

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ID  YEAR    FORCE   NEIGHBOURHOOD   ALL_CRIME   ANTI_SOCIAL_BEHAVIOUR   BURGLARY    CRIMINAL_DAMAGE_AND_ARSON   DRUGS   OTHER_THEFT PUBLIC_DISORDER_AND_WEAPONS ROBBERY SHOPLIFTING VEHICLE_CRIME   VIOLENT_CRIME   OTHER_CRIME
1   2013-03 Police  AAN_HP  290 91  27  33  11  64  8   6   3   14  27  6
```

i need to change the order of theses into something like

```
ID  1
YEAR    2012
FORCE   Police
NEIGHBOURHOOD   Bradford
ALL_CRIME   12345
ANTI_SOCIAL 87
BURGLARY    10
CRIMINAL_DAMAGE 20
DRUGS   15
OTHER_THEFT 30
```

Comment: Rows or columns is just a choice of the *tool* you're using to query with (and the tools commonly used for db development work commonly use a gridlike record=row format), if you need row-based reports you may want to look at one of the bazillion reporting tools out there - or even just use MS Access to generate reports from your Oracle db.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Starting from Oracle 11g you can simply "*unpivot*" that desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to changed the order in which the columns are returning change the order in which you are selecting them

`SELECT 1,2,3 FROM t`

Would return differently from

`SELECT 2,1,3 FROM t`

I don't know if this is what you wanted but I found the question confusingly worded!

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy to do with a query:

```
with lvls as (select /* + materialize */ level lv from dual connect by level <= 9)
select id,
       decode(lv,
              1,'year',
              2,'force'),
              ...
       decode(lv,
              1,to_char(year),
              2,to_char(force),
              ...
from yourtable, lvls
order by id,lv;
```

hint "materialize" will not make Oracle be unperformant (he likes to join here the tables first and then run hierarchy if you do not specify this hint)

Answer (score 0):

- try this

  ```
   select * from your_tab unpivot(col2 for col1 in(ID,YEAR,FORCE,NEIGHBOURHOOD, ALL_CRIME,ANTI_SOCIAL_BEHAVIOUR);
  ```
- note:All columns mentioned in col1 must be of same datatype